# How to make ngrok client listen a specific hostname instead of localhost?

Tags: ngrok

My yaml config is like this:

```
  yarn:
    hostname: "ngrok.xfl.me:810"
    remote_port: 810 
    proto: 
      tcp: 8088
```

My purpose is:

```
Forwarding     https://ngrok.xfl.me:810-> 192.168.0.104:8088
```

But by default, as the config above, ngrok client just listen to `127.0.0.1`. So it failed to connect.

How can I make the ngrok client listen to a certain hostname `192.168.0.104` instead of `localhost`

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was solved with:

```
  yarn:
    hostname: "ngrok.xfl.me:810"
    remote_port: 810 
    proto: 
      tcp: 192.168.0.104:8088
```